# AngularJS in WebStorm

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, webstorm

I am trying to build an application using d3js in WebStorm because I read that it is the best way to organize your AngularJS project.

However, when I start a new project, select AngularJS project there supposed to be a "hello world" example ready where you have your `index.html` pointing to `view1` and then you click `view2`. But what happens in my case is that when I click run `index.html` view1 doesn't appear even when I click on the link leading to it or to view2.

Is there a configuration missing ? Do you know how I can correct that ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a **bower install** to download all the dependencies your project needs ?

Comment: angular, angular-loader, angular-mocks, angular-route and html5-boilerplate are already installed , I verified it by going to settings then bower to install packages and they appear now in bower_components

Comment: But what do you mean by "I click run index.html" though ? You just have to open index.html to see the app working. If that's what you meant, do you have any errors in the console ?

Comment: There is no error in the console, apparently Webstorm is slow because after a number of times clicking on "run index.html" it works and I didn't do anything, and if I make a change in the html code and click run, it shows the page unmodified ...

Comment: What do you "run" ? ... Do you use any task / build runner such as Gulp ? Otherwise, you don't have anything to "run", you can simply double click "index.html" file to open it in a web browser ...

Comment: yes in webstorm there is "Run index.html" same as open in browser , what I don't understand is why when I modify the content of HTML the changes are not shown in the browser

Comment: Do you have the folder **components** inside the folder **app** ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109883/discussion-between-hyukchan-kwon-and-jean).